# Getting Error when using ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT while implementing referential integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried to implement example for referential integrity using ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT but i am getting error.I tried to search about this but i didn't found any appropriate example. Please correct me if i am wrong somewhere in my code or give a example which help me to implement and understand the SET DEFAULT option.

[code script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEKBr.png)

Comment: What is the error? How about posting the ddl for the tables involved and the foreign key? Without these details we can't help.

Comment: click in hyperlink "Code Script". you will come to know everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value needs to exist in the referenced table. It is still a foreign key, and as such needs to have referential integrity.

In your example, you need to have a `tblGender.Id` of `4` before updating `tblGender.Id`  `6` to `7`, so that `tblPerson1` can successfully update to the default of `4`.

For example:

```
create table Themes (
  ThemeID int primary key,
  ThemeName varchar(100),
);
insert into Themes (ThemeID, ThemeName) values (1,'Default'),(2,'Winter');

create table Users(
  UserID int primary key,
  UserName varchar(100),
  ThemeID int default 1 constraint Users_ThemeID_FK 
    /* if the default doesn't exist in the parent table
      , you will get an error on update --*/
    references Themes(ThemeID) 
        on update set default
        on delete set default 
);

insert into Users(UserID, UserName, ThemeID) values 
 (1,'JSmith',null),(2,'Ted',1),(3,'ARod',2)

-- update a theme that isn't the default
update themes set themeid = 3 where ThemeID = 2

-- And let's see what we've got:
select * from Users

-- Try to update the default and you will get an error
--update themes set themeid = 3 where ThemeID = 1
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/NGYBS91102

Reference:

[Using `set null` and `set default` with Foreign Key Constraints - Jeff Smith](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-set-null-and-set-default-with-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Thank you so much SqlZim. i am looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you don't have a matching ID of 4 (the default value) in the Gender table.

If you add this:

```
insert tblGender values (4, 'abc')
```

Then the update statement will run without error.